# Как снять обработчик события, если он был добавлен с применением .bind(this)?

Tags: javascript

Допустим хотим поставить обработчик события, и снять его тут же:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');

function func() {
  console.log('Сработало');
}

button.addEventListener('click', func);
button.removeEventListener('click', func);
```

```html
<button id="button">Кликни</button>
```

Прекрасно, func не сработал.

Но что будет, если в обработчике есть функции с this?

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');

let objWithFunc = {
  func() {
    console.log('Сработало');
  },
  start() {
    function auxiliaryFunc() {
      this.func();
    }
    // Воспользуемся .bind(this) иначе будет ошибка
    button.addEventListener('click', auxiliaryFunc.bind(this));

    // Ни один из следующих методов не снимет обработчик
    button.removeEventListener('click', auxiliaryFunc);
    button.removeEventListener('click', auxiliaryFunc.bind(this));
  }
}

objWithFunc.start();
```

```html
<button id="button">Кликни</button>
```

Как снять обработчик в этом случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.bind()` создаёт новую функцию. Именно её, а не созданную новую, нужно передавать в `removeEventListener`

```
    const listener = auxiliaryFunc.bind(this)
    button.addEventListener('click', listener);
    button.removeEventListener('click', listener);
```

Comment: "Именно её, а не созданную новую" - немного сложно сформулировано, скорее - в `addEventListener` и `removeEventListener` нужно передавать ссылку на одну и ту же функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Немного не по теме, но можно обойтись и без `.bind(this)` в реалиях es6.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');

const objWithFunc = {
  func() {
    console.log('Сработало');
  },
  start() {
    const auxiliaryFunc = () => {
      this.func();
    }
    
    button.addEventListener('click', auxiliaryFunc);
    button.removeEventListener('click', auxiliaryFunc);
  }
}

objWithFunc.start();
```

```html
<button id="button">Кликни</button>
```